# If $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2}=−1$. Show that if $c\in F$ $\exists$ $b_{1}, \dots , b_{k}$ of $F$ satisfying $c =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}b_{i}^{2}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field of characteristic other than $2$ in which
>   there exist elements $a_{1}, \dots , a_{n}$ satisfying $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}^{2}=−1$. Show that for any $c\in F$ there exist elements $b_{1}, \dots , b_{k}$ of $F$ satisfying $c =\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k}b_{i}^{2}$.

I really dont know how to prove that, so needing some help ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** $$c=\left(\frac{1+c}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{1-c}{2}\right)^2$$

Comment: Very good hint. +1

Comment: good one, but since $F$ is an arbitrary field maybe there is not exists $1/2$ like in the $GF(5)$ with $c=2$, there is not $\frac{1+2}{2}$ element

Comment: @José: Didn't you require the field to have characteristic other than $2$ ?

Comment: $1/2$ does exist in $GF(5)$. Any nonzero element of a field is invertible!

Comment: yes I know, just and example, but I really dont know the properties about the characteristic, so how can I use that to assure that there is an element $a$ such that $a+a=1+c$